# im having this error with my Xml Error:(3, 29) No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am getting error when trying to build my **build.gradle** here is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background" />
<item android:left="-36dp">
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/googleg_standard_color_18"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Edit your question and post the code in right format.

Comment: yust did edit it

Comment: Does the signin btn drawable exist in the folder?

Comment: so you mean the PNG ?

Comment: Does this `common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background` exist in the drawable folder?

Comment: yes it does , in the exluded drwable folder

Comment: Why in the excluded drawable folder? The folder won't be used in the final apk.